# Select Lines within a Polygon

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, clip

I would like to select all the lines within a Polygon and the lines have to be cut at the border to the Polygon. The option spatial queries takes the whole line. However I only want the part of the lines which is within the Polygon.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

**[QGIS 2.18]** Use the Clip tool in the processing toolbox/panel :

[image: Clip tool]

> This algorithm clips a vector layer using the polygons of an
>   additional polygons layer. **Only the parts of the features in the input**
>   **layer that falls within the polygons of the clipping layer will be**
>   **added to the resulting layer**. The attributes of the features are not
>   modified, although properties such as area or length of the features
>   will be modified by the cliping operation. If such properties are
>   stored as attributes, those attributes will have to be manually
>   updated.